# How to add more than one ember-power-select components on same page

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js, drop-down-menu, ember-cli, jquery-select2

Im facing problem related to adding more than one field of ember-power-select.
i wants to add a new ember-power-select components in view each time when i will click on "add" button of account information section.
because each "user" can have mulitple accounts.
currently i add two components manually by hard code in template

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px">
          <div class="form-group"  style="padding-bottom:50px">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align:right; margin-top: 3px">Account</label>
              <div class="col-xs-7">
                  {{#power-select-multiple
                  selected=selectedAccount
                  options=accounts
                  searchField ="title"
                  onchange=(action "chooseDestination")
                  onopen=(action "verifyPresence")
                  onkeydown=(action "handleKeydown")
                  as |account|
                  }}
                      {{account.title}}
                  {{/power-select-multiple}}
              </div>
              <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 0px"></i>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px">
          <div class="form-group"  style="padding-bottom:50px">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align:right; margin-top: 10px">Account</label>
              <div class="col-xs-7">
                  {{#power-select-multiple
                  selected=selectedAccount
                  options=accounts
                  searchField ="title"
                  onchange=(action "chooseDestination")
                  onopen=(action "verifyPresence")
                  onkeydown=(action "handleKeydown")
                  as |account|
                  }}
                      {{account.title}}
                  {{/power-select-multiple}}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

But the issue is that both components of ember-select behaves same in short if i select value in one component it also seletec in second component at same time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfmad.png)

Comment: Are both those components bound to the same account ? Seems that way..

Comment: No both should be associated with different accounts

Comment: What is chooseDestination doing?

Comment: Like @TameBadger mentioned, they seem to be associated with the same fields, so it is expected it wouldn't work.